# Root composer.json requires PHP extension ext-calender * but it is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's calender extension

Tags: php

I am trying to install the following package on Laravel and have php 8.1

```
composer require santigarcor/laratrust
```

I am getting this

```
  Problem 1
    - Root composer.json requires PHP extension ext-calender * but it is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's calender extension.

To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:
    - /opt/homebrew/etc/php/8.1/php.ini
    - /opt/homebrew/etc/php/8.1/conf.d/ext-opcache.ini
You can also run `php --ini` in a terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.
Alternatively, you can run Composer with `--ignore-platform-req=ext-calender` to temporarily ignore these required extensions.
You can also try re-running composer require with an explicit version constraint, e.g. "composer require santigarcor/laratrust:*" to figure out if any version is installable, or "composer require santigarcor/laratrust:^2.1" if you know which you need.
```

I am using MacOS. Tried both the following

```
pecl install calendar
```

Got

```
No releases available for package "pecl.php.net/calendar"
install failed
```

And this

```
brew install php-calendar
```

Got

```
Warning: No available formula with the name "php81-calendar".
==> Searching for similarly named formulae and casks...
Error: No formulae or casks found for php81-calendar
```